# Weierstrass decomposition of an explicit function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-geometry

Let $f(z,w) := z^2 + \sin(w)$ for $(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2$. I want to find its weierstrass decomposition as suggested in the Weierstrass preparation theorem.

$f_0(z) := f(z,w) = \sin(w)$ does not vanish, so I want to find a Weierstrass polynomial $g_w(z)$ and a holomorphic function $h$ such that $f = g.h$ and $h(0) \neq 0$. The proof of the WPT states that $g$ is polynomial in the expressions $\sum _{i=1}^d a_i^k(w)$, with $k = 1,…,d$, where $d$ is the number of zeros of $f_w(z)$ counted with multiplicities (in an appropriate disc where any zero occurs as often as determined by its multiplicity) and $a_1(w), …, a_d(w)$ its zeros.
Here, the two zeros of $f$ are $$a_1(w):={\sqrt{-\sin(w)}}, a_2(w):={-\sqrt{-\sin(w)}}.$$
My issue is how to find explicitly the Weierstrass polynomial $g$ with these two zeros $a_1(w)$ and $a_2(w)$. Any suggestion would be nice, thanks.

Comment: I didn't know this theorem, but, based on the definition given on Wikipedia, your function seems already decomposed, because you can write $f(z,w) = g(z,w)h(z,w)$ with $h \equiv 1$ and $g(z,w) = z^2 + g_1(w)z+g_2(w)$ where $g_1 \equiv 0$ and $g_2(w) = \sin w$. Everything is analytic, with $h(0,0)  \neq 0$ and $g_1(0)=g_2(0)=0$, as required by the theorem.

Comment: @Abezhiko Well that is embarrassing ! One time  I tought it could be already decomposed but I did not believe it because this is a problem suggested in some lectures notes about the theorem. But what you wrote makes sense, thank you very much.